# ScaleAnimation of image as Circle instead of Square from Centre

Tags: android, android-animation, scaling

I am new to Android. I am developing a simple app. In this I need scaling of image as circular instead of like Square/Rectangle on Android 4.4.
I tried many link which i found on internet, but they didn't work.

I am using following code for ScaleAnimation:

```
 <scale
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:duration="200"/>
```

Does anyone have any clue how to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling from a "circle" is an odd requirement. The code above will scale linearly in each direction, and you can put circular images into it and it should appear to scale properly.

Your problem is probably in understanding how "pivot" works - if you have a circle, then you will need it centered, otherwise it will scale wrong. If you have a circle that is not centered, then you are not understanding how scaling works in general.

Unless, and this is possible but very unlikely, you really want "polar scaling" based on the angle in a circle, in which case you will almost certainly need to build a custom tool.